# Interactive 3d Model Animation In Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I have just started this week in exploring Android Open GL ES and related 3d android game engines. During my exploration I got to know some good information and confused in others and could not understand how it will work.

Simply In points:

3D Model should be created in Software like 3d Max, Blender or Maya.

Converting model object to xml file (meshes tags) that could be read by java (one of many ways)

If there is an animation it will be exported as frames of time also into xml file (frames tags)

By these points I can animate 3D model in android in a specific animation.

The issue is:

How to make the animation interactive not specific, i.e. the model should go left or right in response of touch event in android device screen.

I also read about skeletal animation, Automatic Rigging and Forward kinematic animation but I'm not sure if it is related to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also read about skeletal animation, Automatic Rigging and Forward kinematic animation but I'm not sure if it is related to my question.

Yes, it very much is. Look into these techniques with regards to OpenGL. Skeletal structures and the like are the methods for creating interactive animations. Just note that these techniques are complex. Once you have learned more about them, make sure that this is actually what you require. Key-frame animation (what you mentioned earlier in your post) is a simpler concept, and if it will fit your requirements, I suggest using this approach.